# Select UPPER CASE list items with spaces and punctuation

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering

I have a sample list that includes people's names in Title Case, and their companies in UPPER CASE.

```
list = {"Bob Jones", "ACME-SYSTEMS", "John Smith", "FUTURETECH123", 
  "Sally Jones", "CITY SCHOOL", "Jane Black", "CONSULTANT", 
  "Max Speed", "A.B. CORP"}
```

I would like to select only the list items that are in upper case.  The most obvious approach would be to use `UpperCaseQ`:

```
Select[list, UpperCaseQ]
(*{"CONSULTANT"}*)
```

Unfortunately, `UpperCaseQ` returns `FALSE` for any list item that has a non letter characters such as space or punctuation in it.

I did find that I can incorporate `StringReplace` within `UpperCaseQ` to ignore some symbols:

```
Select[list, UpperCaseQ[StringReplace[#, {" ", "-", "."} -> ""]] &]
(*{"ACME-SYSTEMS", "CITY SCHOOL", "CONSULTANT", "A.B. CORP"}*)
```

Besides spaces, periods and hyphens, there is also the issue of numbers and symbols in strings (hence FUTURETECH123 being off the list).  On a small dataset, you can hand code the exceptions, but as you get larger, you would need to automate it.

I was able to come up with this code as a way to automatically select the non letter characters, but I would think running the code on a very large document would not be very efficient.

```
allcharacters = 
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Characters[list]]]; nonletters = 
 Select[allcharacters, LetterQ[#] == False &];
Select[list, UpperCaseQ[StringReplace[#, nonletters -> ""]] &]
(*{"ACME-SYSTEMS","FUTURETECH123","CITY SCHOOL","CONSULTANT","A.B. CORP"}*)
```

Is there a more simple way to select items in a list that are UPPER CASE while ignoring the non letter characters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code might not be quite fast but it takes into account foreign languages.

```
list = {"Bob Jones", "ACME-SYSTEMS", "John Smith", "FUTURETECH123", 
   "Sally Jones", "CITY SCHOOL", "Jane Black", "CONSULTANT", 
   "Max Speed", "A.B. CORP", "TЯUMP", "яUSSIam"};
Select[list, ToUpperCase[#] === # &]
```

You can see it catches the Russian TЯUMP.

---

**UPDATE**

Apparently, Russians cannot be caught. In the example below, an accented letter á (as those used in Spanish) is processed by the system but the Russian one is quite stealthy.

```
string = "áа";
ToCharacterCode[string]
ToUpperCase[string]
(*
{225, 1072}
"Áа"
*)
```

Comment: What a simple solution.  Now just to make sure I am following correctly, the code is essentially selecting all items in the list where using `ToUpperCase` produces the exact same result as the original item.  Right?

Comment: @kickert Yes, exactly.

Comment: "Russian TЯUMP." That's a good one! ;)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest regex that I can think of that does what the OP asks is the following:

```
list // Pick[#, StringContainsQ[#, RegularExpression["^[^a-z]+$"]]] &
```

> "ACME-SYSTEMS", "FUTURETECH123", "CITY SCHOOL", "CONSULTANT", "A.B. \
>   CORP"}

For the cases [discussed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178619/106) by [Hector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8803/hector), maybe:

```
Join[list, {"TЯUMP", "яUSSIam", "ЯЯ", "TЯЯUMP", "Яя", "TЯяUMP"}] 
// Pick[#, StringContainsQ[#, RegularExpression["^[^a-zа-я]+$"]]] &
```

> {"ACME-SYSTEMS", "FUTURETECH123", "CITY SCHOOL", "CONSULTANT", "A.B. \
>   CORP", "TЯUMP", "ЯЯ", "TЯЯUMP"}

**Original WRONG answer**

```
list2 // Pick[#, StringContainsQ[#, RegularExpression["[ALPHA]"]]] &
```

> {"ACME-SYSTEMS", "FUTURETECH123", "CITY SCHOOL", "CONSULTANT", "A.B. \
>   CORP", "TЯUMP"}

A very beautiful solution, which gives the right answer.  Things began to unravel, however, when I read [Hector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8803/hector)'s comment, got an unexpected result, and tried the following:

```
 list// Pick[#, StringContainsQ[#, RegularExpression["[ALPHB]"]]]&
```

> {"Bob Jones", "ACME-SYSTEMS", "FUTURETECH123", "CITY SCHOOL", "Jane \
>   Black", "CONSULTANT", "A.B. CORP"}

Comment: A coworker of mine just suggested looking into `RegularExpression` for this problem.  Seems like a great option for more complicated string manipulations.  Thanks for the alternative approach.

Comment: @tomd My version of MMA does not have StringContainsQ. Do you mind checking the result of your approach on "Яя". I noticed MMAv9 does not classify the Russian alphabet (even thought my OS does). I am wondering whether regular expressions in MMA are any better in latter versions of MMA.

Comment: @Hector.  On reading your comment, I realized my original solution was wrong! I have modified it to use the simplest regex that I can think of that does what the OP asks.  I prefer your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"Bob Jones", "ACME-SYSTEMS", "John Smith", "FUTURETECH123", 
  "Sally Jones", "CITY SCHOOL", "Jane Black", "CONSULTANT", 
  "Max Speed", "A.B. CORP"}

Pick[list, StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ Alphabet[]] /@ list
 , False
 ]
```

OR

```
Pick[list, StringFreeQ[Alternatives @@ Alphabet[]] /@ list
 , True
 ]
```

OR

```
Select[list, 
 UpperCaseQ@
   StringDelete[
     PunctuationCharacter | DigitCharacter | Whitespace][#] &
 ]
```

> {"ACME-SYSTEMS", "FUTURETECH123", "CITY SCHOOL", "CONSULTANT", "A.B. CORP"}